# Seaching for two values even if one is not present

Tags: mysql, select

I can only make a successful search if both the genre and the artist parameters are present, but I want to be able if one of them is not.

```
param. present ->       genre      artist      both                            
working                                         x
not working               x          x
```

```
SELECT cover,id,price FROM songs WHERE genre=? && artist=? ORDER BY title DESC
```

I tried to check, put, and play with 'NULL' values and 'OR' statements everywhere, but it didn't work out.

Keep in mind, I have simplified this greatly, and because there are in fact much more categories present, an 'if/else' solution with a database query for each combination is not economical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cover,id,price FROM songs WHERE (genre=?) OR (artist=?)
```

will cover the situations where

1. only genre is present
2. only artist is present
3. both are present